# Which founding fathers pushed for the right to bear arms?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution

Which members of the constitutional convention wrote and/or pushed for the right to bear arms?  Did anyone fight it?

Comment: Please show preliminary research.  The right to bear arms is in an amendment.  Amendments were not introduced until after the Constitution was adopted. Pauline Maier's book on the Constitution may be helpful

Answer (score 11):

Turns out there wasn't much of a "push" involved. The right to bear arms predates the US constitution, and had been seen as an extension of the natural right to self-defense in English culture well before. In fact, the issue had been raised well before US independence, with king James II attempting to disarm his Protestant subjects (James himself was pro-Catholic). In the wake of King James II's deposition in the Glorious Revolution ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glorious_Revolution)) the Parliament of England approved the 1689 Bill of Rights, guaranteeing certain civil rights in England. The right for protestant subjects bear arms for self-defense is included.

During the American pre-Revolutionary period, the right to bear and keep arms was both a pragmatic and idealistic issue. Allowing arms to the population was important for safety on the developing frontier areas as well as a natural right that needed to be protected. The Parliament attempted to prevent firearm exports to America to avoid armed uprisings, something seen by the Patriot side as a infringement of their natural rights not unlike what James II had done.

The Revolution came, the Patriot side won and the United States got its independence. The US constitution borrowed heavily from ideals set in English common law, including the right to keep arms codified in the Second Amendment. The amendment was proposed by James Madison ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Madison)) as a part of his Bill of Rights. The amendment was ratified without much controversy - it didn't really change anything much, just set current practice into law.

Comment: Very important to understand that "Congress" (we were printing worthless Continentals to finance the War) couldn't imagine a scenario where there could be a military victory under such chaos. They reviewed the Troops and saw nothing but losing until a flock of ducks flew over and these "pre-Lincolns" opened fired and slaughtered the whole flock. Very uplifting moment for our hapless Government back then...so the Man and his Gun headed West as a consequence. In short....the entire US Government encouraged everyone to be locked and loaded for the next hundred years....